# Video Html5 No funciona en Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, video, chrome

Quiero mostrar un video y funciona bien en computadora, pero en android no. Busque ayuda pero no funciono.

//// Codigo

```
<video poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video" controls>
    <source src="ejemplo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

////

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos la salida de un `ffmpeg -i ejemplo.mp4` o decirnos qué códecs de audio y vídeo usa ese archivo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en chrome para Android  nececitas un elemento que inicie el video
agrega un id al elemento:

```
    <video id="video" poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video" controls>
    <source src="ejemplo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

y un script:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

y

Comment: Pero no quiero el autoplay, solo con que se reprodusca. O quizas  no estoy entendiendo, Aparte si solo agrego el script ese, deberia de funcionar?

Comment: Acabo de descargar firefox en android y si funciona. Osea que el problema es chrome.

Comment: Es que en chrome para android debes llamar a la funcion video.play() de esta manera asi lo diseño google

Comment: Pegue ese script pero no funciona, le tengo que agregar algo mas? Porque la verdad no entiendo script solo html.

Comment: añadiste el id en el elemento video?

Comment: Este script lo que hace es lo siguiente: En tu HTML le añades un `id` a tu vídeo. En el javascript, en `getElementById("id")` poner la `id` que le diste, entonces cuando hagas click sobre ese `id` hará un play.

Comment: No es necesario asignar un `id` al elemento, basta con usar la clase  (`document.querySelector('.fullscreen-bg__video')`) o la etiqueta (`document.querySelector('video')`) si sólo hay uno. También se puede usar `querySelectorAll` para aplicarlo a todos los vídeos de la página.

Answer (score 0):

Es script sí funciona, pero hay que dar con el dedo en la imagen. Tened en cuenta en el css el **z-index**, si hay capas por encima el click con el dedo no funcionará.

Esto tampoco va (jquery):

```
$( document ).ready(
    function() {
        $('#video').play(); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Supongo que querías decir `$('.fullscreen-bg__video')` en vez de `('#video')` y, además, debes usar `.get(0).play()` en vez de `.play()` porque `.play()` es un método del DOM, no de jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no todos los navegadores soportan todos los formatos de vídeo y/o códecs de audio y vídeo, por lo que si el navegador chrome de android no soporta el que usas no se reproducirá correctamente.

Para solucionar el problema HTML5 te facilita el trabajo permitiendo varias fuentes de vídeo:

```html
<video poster="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/578146756_1280x720.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video" controls width="560" height="360"> 
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" />
  <source type="video/ogg" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" />
  <source type="video/3gp" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp" />
</video>
```

Yo te recomiendo tener el vídeo, como mínimo, en MP4 y WebM.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo sin selección que me funciona en Chrome para Android:

```html
<video poster="http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/578146756_1280x720.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video" controls width="560" height="360"> 
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
</video>
```

Sin embargo otros vídeos MP4 no me funcionan, por lo que es probable que sea debido a un códec de vídeo o audio no soportado, pero teniendo alternativas el navegador es capaz de elegir la que pueda usar correctamente.